# sae_require_mfp=1 on hostapd and wpa3

Tags: wpa3

I heard wpa3 is more secure with mfp.

I have a WPA AP using `hostapd`.
On `/etc/hostapd.conf` I have set it "forced"

```
ieee80211w=2
```

I see also this option about mfp

```
sae_require_mfp=1
```

Is sae_require_mfp useless with ieee80211w=2 or is better to enable it?

In the docs I understand sae_require_mfp is needed only with ieee80211w=1, but I prefer a confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: the answer is

```
# Require MFP for all associations using SAE
# This parameter can be used to enforce negotiation of MFP for all associations
# that negotiate use of SAE. This is used in cases where SAE-capable devices are
# known to be MFP-capable and the BSS is configured with optional MFP
# (ieee80211w=1) for legacy support. The non-SAE stations can connect without
# MFP while SAE stations are required to negotiate MFP if sae_require_mfp=1.
#sae_require_mfp=0
```

My config use

```
ieee80211w=2
```

so the line sae_require_mfp is useless

```
# ieee80211w: Whether management frame protection (MFP) is enabled
# 0 = disabled (default)
# 1 = optional
# 2 = required
#ieee80211w=0
# The most common configuration options for this based on the PMF (protected
# management frames) certification program are:
# PMF enabled: ieee80211w=1 and wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP WPA-EAP-SHA256
# PMF required: ieee80211w=2 and wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP-SHA256
# (and similarly for WPA-PSK and WPA-PSK-SHA256 if WPA2-Personal is used)
# WPA3-Personal-only mode: ieee80211w=2 and wpa_key_mgmt=SAE
```

If we use WPA3 only the options

ieee80211w=2 and wpa_key_mgmt=SAE

are ok.

source: https://github.com/vanhoefm/hostap-wpa3/blob/master/hostapd/hostapd.conf